# Какие методы и операторы необходимы для использования типа в качестве параметра стандартного шаблонного контейнера?

Tags: c++, stl

Какие методы и операторы необходимы для использования типа в качестве параметра стандартного шаблонного контейнера?

Comment: Таких нет. Вы можете хоть базовый тип `int` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

У разных контейнеров разные требования.
Требования могут быть указаны в описаниях функций контейнера, например:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());

Requires: T shall be DefaultInsertable into *this.
```

где `DefaultInsertable` требует чтобы следующее выражение было корректным:

```
allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(n, p)
```

Обычно требования проверяются в той функции контейнера которая их использует, т.е. например оператор сравнения требуется только если используется функция

```
template <class T, class Allocator>
bool operator< (const vector<T, Allocator>& x, const vector<T, Allocator>& y);
```